# Excel matching or move to next matc

Tags: excel, search

So I am trying to teach an introductory biology lab, if it was not for that this would be much easier, but for the students I have to keep things in two separate columns instead of one.  Okay, with that said here is what I have and what I need:

first, each row is an individual male and female and the columns represent their "gene"

We have a female and male that are going to mate, so the respective genes (two copies for each male and female) have an A allele and a B allele, we are only concerned about the males.  I need a function that 80% of the time the female will not "mate" with a male with two of the same copies (BB), and will move down to the next male.  So the males' letters are in column C and D.  It will randomly donate either the letter from C or D to the new offspring, we do this by setting columns F & G for the male

```
=if(rand()>0.5,C1,D1)
```

That goes into E and F columns.  Now comes the part about fusing it with the female (in columns G and H, easy enough just concatenate them.  But I need picky females that do not like males with a B in both the C and D column, and will 80 % of the time find a male that has either A in both C and D or has A in one and B in the other (doesn't matter which column they go into).

What I have so far:

```
=IF($C1="B"&$D1="B",if(rand()>0.2,concatenate($E1,$G1),???????)
```

so where I have the question marks I need something that finds the first male (i.e. row) where $C? & $D? are not "B" and then concatenate($E?,$G?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just cannot figure out how to search and find the first row that meets those requirements.  It is pretty much the searching part I cannot figure out, not the meeting the requirements.

Comment: "finds the first male" below the current row? Also, what is in columns A & B? Finally, there is *always* a mating that occurs? What happens at the end of the population when there are no "$C? & $D? are not 'B' and then concatenate" males left? It would actually be great if you could mock up some ASCII art (or a screen shot) showing some of the data with column headers and what the mating output looks like (even if it were based on *fixed* random mating), just so one gets a feel for what is needed.

Comment: With the complexity of the question provided, your solution is going to involve a bunch of nested if statements or a Macro. I agree with Werner in requesting a mockup or screenshot of your problem for clarification.

Comment: Also, are males or females (or both) monogamous?  Do females always mate?  I'll add my vote for a mockup or screenshot.  I also think that a macro will be your best bet and more easily implemented.

Comment: Okay, females always mate with the male in the same row, unless it meets the qualifications I have above.

Comment: Okay, females always mate with the male in the same row, unless it meets the qualifications I have above.<img src="http://i927.photobucket.com/albums/ad115/misterid/screen.png" width="100" height="100"> The error is me messing around. So, M19 is the cat of E19 and F19.  So I need to check if C19 and D19 are both "B" and if they are 20% of the time the female for row 19 will mate (i.e., M19 will be the cat of E and F 19), the rest of the time the female in row 19 will find a new male and M19 will be the result of E19 and FXX where X is the row of the new male. I need to learn macros.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of editing time.